# calculate a probability of a Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

> Let $\{X_t\}_{t\geqslant 0}$ be a Poisson process with parameter $\Lambda\geqslant 0$. Calculate $\mathbb{P}[X_1\gt 1 │ X_3 = 5]$.

I was thinking to calculate this with definition conditional probability but i don't understand this: $\mathbb{P}[X_1 \gt 1 , X_3=5]$.How can I see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

This is a union of all events $\{X_1 = a, X_3 = 5\}$ where $a > 1$. In other words,
$$
\{X_1>1, X_3 = 5\} = \bigcup_{a>1} \{X_1 = a, X_3 = 5\} 
$$

Comment: all events are disjoint, right?

Comment: @angieduque the ones on the RHS certainly are

Comment: then i have the sum of these events, so by property of independent variables this is a sum of products, right?

Comment: @angieduque yes, correct. And if $X_1$ were a continuous random variable, it would be an integral...

Comment: I have the sum of probabilities p(x(a) =a) so i have the acumulative function ?

Comment: @angieduque you need the joint probability of $X_1$ and $X_3$ together